# How does the 'replace' string method work with caret as regex and String function as arguments?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking over some purposefully obfuscated code for online challenge. I am looking for clarification for a line. I know this will return true, just like !'' will return true. But it seems like the rest of the code will never do anything. I assume this is just to make the problem look more confusing. I would appreciate some deep technical details of what is going on.

I know what the code currently returns, but I am curious about how this works at a deeper level. I looked up the 'replace' string method, and I understand how it can take a regex and a function that operates on each match. I also looked up the String function and understand it is just casting things as strings. I know that regex caret matches begin of line.

```
// note: typeof String === "function"
!''.replace(/^/, String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to explain what it's doing is to make it slightly more complicated first.

The first thing to note is that the [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, when called with a callback function, will pass the `match`, then any captured groups (in this case none), then `offset`, then `string` as arguments, so what it can be expanded to is this:

```
!''.replace(/^/, (match, offset, string) => String(match, offset, string))
```

Now, when [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is called as a static method (without the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator), it takes its first parameter and converts it to a string, ignoring the rest of the parameters passed:

```js
console.log(String('foo', 0, 'foo bar')) // 0, 'foo bar' ignored
```

Given that, we can simplify the expression now to this:

```
!''.replace(/^/, match => match)
```

since `match` is already a string. Now the `/^/` matches the zero-width section at the beginning of the string the method is called on, and `replace()` inserts the return value of the callback function into the same location. Since the `match` *is* the return value, the whole `.replace(/^/, match => match)` causes no side-effects, so the expression is now equivalent to:

```
!''
```

And, as you already pointed out, `''` is falsy, so `!''` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it, `''.replace(/^/, String)` indeed does absolutely nothing that `''` doesn't.

Comment: In fact, `x.replace(/^/, String)` where `typeof x === 'string'` will always be the same as `x`

Comment: The `!` winds up converting `''` (a false-y) value to `true`. Not knowing what the rest of the code is doing or why, it looks like they're converting false-y empty string to boolean `true`?

Answer (score -1):

```
'hello'.replace(/^/, 'world'); // 'worldhello'
'hello'.replace(/e/, String); // 'hello'
'hello'.replace(/^/, String); // 'hello'
''.replace(/^/, String); // ''
!''.replace(/^/, String); // true
```

Replace by `String` does nothing.

Negating `''`  cast `''` to a boolean (ie false) and negate it.

And voilà, you have it, `!''.replace(/^/, String)` evaluates to true.